# Simple panning of a canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, panning

I wanted to add a zoom/pan feature to a canvas. I have the zooming working fine, but I'm having issues with the panning. The closest I got was being able to pan with extreme shaking of the canvas and then the zoom feature not working at all.

I have three methods right now that are subscribed to by the canvas in the xaml. The first and last capture/release the mouse respectively, but I can't figure out the mouseMove function. I've tried several different transforms on the canvas but to no avail. I've also looked at plenty of examples. I understand I have a starting point which is where the mouse is first clicked, and then I need to offset that based on where the mouse is moved, but what transform should take place?